# Discord bot not showing up in a server

Tags: python, discord

I've created a bot and added to a server that I created for the purpose of bot testing as well as a server that I have admin permissions in. In the server I created, I can see that the bot is online and a member and can call the commands with no issue. However, I cannot see the bot in the other server and cannot call the commands.

I followed the same procedure for adding the bot to both servers by going thru the OAuth2 api.

I know that the bot connected to both servers because when I run:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    print(bot.guilds)
```

I see both servers in the output.

Not really sure what the issue here is. If anyone can shed some light on potential causes of this issue. I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT: I also see the bot in the 'Integrations' tab of 'Server Settings' for both servers.

Comment: If I need to provide more info please let me know, no need to downvote. Not sure what additional code I can provide...

Comment: Are you sure that you have invited your bot to the server?

Comment: I'm sure. I can see the bot in the integrations tab of server settings in both servers. And I see the server name when I output `bot.guilds`.

Comment: Maybe kick and have it rejoin?

Comment: Also, when you call commands in the server which it disappeared in, are there any errors? If so, could you add them to the question?

Comment: Just removed the integration and re-added, no luck. No errors, no response at all either in discord or in console.

Comment: OH, I figured it out. I was calling the command in locked channels. I guess the bot doesn't have access to those locked channels? It worked in a non-locked channel:)